# definition of image of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

i was looking for a definition but couldn't found the apropriate meaning of what im looking for, (english isnt my native language).
suppose i have a function $f:A\rightarrow B,(A, B\neq \emptyset)$ and a set $C\subseteq A$.
Is the definition of $f[C]$ is $f[C]=\{b\in B \vert \exists a\in A|f(a)=b\}$ is correct

thank you!

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I cannot tell what exactly is the problem: you say you are looking for a definition, but you have a definition already. So what are you trying to find or solve precisely?

Comment: I think the definition should be $f(C)=\{f(c)|c\in C\}=\{b\in B|\exists c\in C:f(c)=b\}$

Comment: is the definition correct? because ive seen the symbol of $f[C]$ and wanted to get a precise definition, so is my definition correct?

Comment: @PeterMelech no its square brackets

Comment: As I pointed out in my comment: the definition doesn't make sense, $C$ is not even involved in that definition, a senseful definition would be th eone I gave above

Comment: What do the square brackets mean?

Comment: @PeterMelech oh yes i said that $Aa\in A$ instead of $a\in C$ but thats what i meant. anyway thank you!

Comment: $\{b\in B:\exists a\in A:f(a)=b\}=im(f)=f(A)$ is the image of $f$ in $B$, no subset $C$ is involved in that definition, I obviously don't get what You are up to, but the definition You give for $f[C]$ should really depend on $C$

Comment: See [Image of a subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Definition)

Comment: yes i meant to write $f[C]=\{ b\in B \vert \exists a \in C \vert f(a)=b \}$ 
so now it is involved

Comment: Yes, that definition is correct!

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome.